# Git fatal: bad object refs/heads 2/master

Tags: git, github

After a few month not working on some static website, I came back and tried to pull changes from a GitHub repo.

The following `fatal: bad object refs/heads 2/master` error occured.

```
(base) ➜  github_repo git:(master) ✗ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 21, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 21 (delta 3), reused 3 (delta 3), pack-reused 18
Unpacking objects: 100% (21/21), 6.95 KiB | 790.00 KiB/s, done.
fatal: bad object refs/heads 2/master
error: https://github.com/asafmaman101/asafmaman101.github.io.git did not send all necessary objects
```

Tried some solutions for similar problems here from StackOverflow and tried also to update Git version on my mac.

Nothing helped.
I'm trying to prevent from deleting local copy and re-cloning the repo because I have local changes that I don't want to lose. Any other ideas?

Comment: Run `git ls-remote` to see if there is such a ref `refs/heads 2/master`. If there is, it should be removed.

Comment: Hi, there is `refs/heads/master` but no `2/master`. I suppose that might be the problem - how should I fix it?

Comment: Look inside your `.git/refs` directory. Is there a `heads` and also a `heads 2`? If so, this looks like something done by Dropbox or iCloud. You're going to have to resolve it manually, and also stop storing `.git` directories in cloud-managed spaces.

Answer (score 27):

I had a similar problem with a " 2" suffix being added to a filename within the `.git` directory. The git repository is in a directory synced by iCloud Drive, so presumably iCloud in its infinite wisdom added the suffix during a sync operation.

I originally encountered the issue via a cryptic error message in SourceTree. Running `git gc` on the command line helped me narrow down the issue:

```
> git gc
fatal: bad object refs/heads/1.2 2
fatal: failed to run repack
```

I was able to fix the issue by removing the " 2" suffix:

```
> mv .git/refs/heads/1.2\ 2 .git/refs/heads/1.2
```

Comment: Yup, worked for me. I think it was Google Drive in my case. Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me too, thanks! I'm on a Mac, so I hit cmd+shift+period to show hidden files, then just navigated to the hidden .git folder in my directory, drilled down, and got rid of the offending "(1)" suffix on my problem file. Yep, I think was Google Drive in my case as well.

Comment: worked for a similar case for me twice today. I think iCloud messed up

Comment: In my case the branch name is develop_abc (2). So you ned to run command refs/head/develop_abc\ * .git/refs/heads/develop_abc

Answer (score 11):

to elaborate on @Robin's answer
here is what worked for me:

first, check the content of the origin directory

```
ls -l .git/refs/remotes/origin
```

result was
HEAD
HEAD 2
..

so, what i did is I removed the duplicate `HEAD 2` file using

```
rm '.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD 2'
```

then I fetched the remotes branches using

```
git fetch
```

then set local branch to track remote branch

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/{YOUR_REMOTE_BRANCH}
```

that's it.